# All fields are not displaying in PHP $_POST as well as $_REQUEST

Tags: php, html

I have a form

```
    <form
    method="post"
    class="c-form"
    action="mail.php"
    id="contactform"
>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="error-alert"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input
                type="text"
                id="subject" name="subject"value="<?php echo $deviceType['device_type_name']; ?> Repair"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="NAME"
                id="name"
                name="name"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="EMAIL"
                id="email"
                name="email"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"
                name="phone"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <textarea
                rows="5"
                placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"
                id="message"
                name="message"
            ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input
                type="submit"
                class="submit"
                value="Contact Us"
                id="submit"
            />
            <img
                src="images/ajax-loader.gif"
                class="loader"
                alt=""
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I submit the form two fields (subject and message) isn't showing in the $_POST or $_REQUEST array (other 3 fields name, phone and email is present in the array). (the variable $deviceType['device_type_name']; has value, so there is no issue there)

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here.

mail.php file (nothing much here just for debugging):

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
die();?>
```

Comment: Can we have code for `mail.php` file too?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. I copy/pasted your form and it works as expected. All fields are being posted correctly.

Comment: I have updated my question with the mail.php file code

Comment: do you have any javascript that is possibly altering your form, ie. setting those inputs to disabled?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What!! Do I have to restart my server then?

Comment: @W.Kabir try form with `novalidate`  e.g. `<form action = "mail.php" method = "post" novalidate>`

Comment: No space there: `name="subject"value="`

Comment: @DineshSuthar - `novalidate` makes no difference here since there's no validation rules anywhere.

Comment: @kerbholz - It should still work (just tested it) and it wouldn't explain why the "message"-textarea isn't submitted.

Comment: Please answer the question @Sean asked

Comment: Since you're echoing a PHP variable in the value for `subject`, check that the generated HTML looks correct.

Comment: @Sean you might be right, because it works with only those two files. Actually I'm not in charge of the front-end part. Thanks everyone for your prompt response. Let me take a look at the javascript portions

Comment: @Sean you are right. Thanks for your help. The code to post those specific fields are in the javascript files.

You are a lifesaver.